# Interpolating polynomial - relation between uniqueness and the error of approximation

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

If I use an interpolating polynomial to approximate the value of funcion $f$ at given $x$ and the polynomial is unique does it mean that the value of the polynomial is equal to the value of $f$ ($error = 0$) for evry $x$ in the function's domain? If so, then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is No. The value of the polynomial is equal to the value of $f$ only at the points of interpolating. [See this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html)